<Suspense fallback={<Loader />}> throws Uncaught Error: window is not defined
I am trying to apply Loader to a page that displays data fetched by a GraphQL query. For the same, I tried the following:
<Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
  <div>
    {fetched data}
  </div
</Suspense>

But using this, The React.Suspense component throws an internal error -
Uncaught Error: window is not definedThis image provides the detailed error
I want the Loader to work normally without any error using Suspense or any other method in NextJS 14. Any ideas about how to achieve this?

There's likely something in your loader component that requires access to the window object. Did you add a "use client" directive at the top? If you did and it still doesn't work, you could import it dynamically but I'm not sure that that would actually fix your issue with the suspense component specifically.
